# How to access elements of char array passed as a parameter to a function in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this function which receives a pointer to char array and initializes it to be `len` repetitions of "a":

```
void test(char ** s, int len) {
    *s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        *(s[i]) = 'a';
    }
    printf("%s\n", *s);
}
```

in the `main()` I have this code:

```
char * s;
test(&s, 3);
```

but I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` error when I run `main()`. The error occurs on the second iteration of the for loop in this line: `*(s[i]) = 'a';`

As far as I understand I'm not accessing the elements correctly, what is the correct way?

Comment: I don't think you have to use a double pointer. Also, I'm going to assume you cannot use [memset](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) for this project?

Comment: Should be `(*s)[i] = 'a'`. But you need to null terminate your string if you are going to print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is declared as a pointer to a pointer. In reality, it's a pointer to a pointer to the start of an array, but that cannot be inferred from the type system alone. It could just as well be a pointer to a start of an array of pointers, which is how `s[i]` treats it. You need to first derefence `s` (to get the pointer to the array's start), and then index on it:

```
(*s)[i] = 'a';
```

Also, as @MFisherKDX correctly pointed out in comments, if you're going to pass `*s` to `printf` or any other standard string-manipulation function, you have to turn into a proper C string by terminating it with a 0 character.

Answer (score 3):

This more clearly shows what you should be doing, while staying close to your original code:

```
void test(char ** s, int len) {
    char *p = malloc(len);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p[i] = 'a';
    }
    printf("%s\n", p);
    *s = p;
}
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is always one by definition, and in C there's no need to cast the result of `malloc()`.

That code also has all your original problems in that it doesn't actually create a string that you can send to `printf( "%s... )`.  This fixes that problem:

```
void test(char ** s, int len) {
    char *p = malloc(len+1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p[i] = 'a';
    }
    p[i]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", p);
    *s = p;
}
```

And this is even easier, with no need to use a double-`*` pointer:

```
char *test(int len) {
    char *p = malloc(len+1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p[i] = 'a';
    }
    p[i]='\0';
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assignment

```
*(s[i]) = 'a';
```

use this:

```
(*s)[i] = 'a';
```

But do not forget that C/C++ strings are [null terminated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/what-is-a-null-terminated-string)

Or you can use this approach to get more readable code:

```
void test(char** s, int len) {
    // 1 char extra for zero
    char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len+1));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        str[i] = 'a';

    // zero terminated string
    str[len] = 0;

    printf("%s\n", str);

    *s = str;
}
```